# Does Collada format support Shading animation?

Tags: animation, collada, dae

How can I animate textures or shaders and have them be saved in the Collada format?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: I don't think you really can. There did use to be some support for it before 2.8. Animating the material's Viewport Display Color is I think the only part that still works (can be exported and imported back in at least).